# help with php search

Tags: php, mysql

How would I do let the user know if there wasnt any rows found?
And if it finds (for example) 26 rows I want it to print that it found 26 hits (Your search for "hey" gave 26 results)

```
$name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['player_name']);

$q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM players WHERE name LIKE '%$name%'");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($q)) { 

$name  = $row['name']; 

    echo "<ul>\n"; 
    echo "<li>" . "<a  href=\"player-info.php?id=\">"   .$name . " </a></li>\n"; 
    echo "</ul>"; 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `mysql_num_rows`:

```
$rowCount = mysql_num_rows($q);
if ($rowCount === 0)
{
    echo 'Found nothing!';
}
else
{
    echo "Found $rowCount rows!";
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($q))
    { 
        $name  = $row['name'];
        echo "<ul>\n"; 
        echo "<li>" . "<a  href=\"player-info.php?id=\">"   .$name . " </a></li>\n"; 
        echo "</ul>"; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out [mysql_num_rows](http://php.net/mysql_num_rows)

Answer (score 1):

[mysql_num_rows](http://uk.php.net/mysql_num_rows)

```
$numberOfResults = mysql_num_rows($q);
```